# Spring mvc : Google api giving Null pointer for JSON key

Tags: java, spring-mvc, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am working on a Spring-MVC project in which I would like to use Google calendar functionality. I used the sample code from [Google sample code](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/cmdline/CalendarSample.java) and I am trying to implement it. I have the ProjectName.json key which is used these days by google for authorization. I am getting a null pointer exception. Kindly check out what I am doing wrong. The key is located in src/main/resources/keys/key.json. Here is the code :

```
  public void authorizeAndTest(){

        try {
            httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
            Credential credential = authorize();

            client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(httpTransport,JSON_FACTORY,credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

            showCalenders();
            addCalendarsUsingBatch();
            Calendar calendar = addCalendar();
            updateCalendar(calendar);
            addEvent(calendar);
            showEvents(calendar);
            deleteCalendarInBatch();
            deleteCalendar(calendar);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Credential authorize() throws Exception{
// The line of code below is throwing me an error. I will paste the error log.
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
                new InputStreamReader(OAuth.class.getResourceAsStream("keys/c0cc3b4b7502.json")));
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
                || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=calendar "
                            + "into calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
            return null;
        }

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport,JSON_FACTORY,clientSecrets,
                Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory).build();

// Is this where I pass the email address for which I am trying to get calendar???
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user@gmail.com");
    }
```

Error code :

```
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.load(Lcom/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory;Ljava/io/Reader;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleClientSecrets;
    com.journaldev.spring.utility.OAuth.authorize(OAuth.java:72)
    com.journaldev.spring.utility.OAuth.authorizeAndTest(OAuth.java:54)
    com.journaldev.spring.controller.PersonController.listCanvas(PersonController.java:596)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

POM.xml :

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev119-1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.47.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev118-1.18.0-rc</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0-rc</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev119-1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1-beta</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess the problem is this part (can't find the json because of wrong path)

```
OAuth.class.getResourceAsStream("keys/app-name-c0cc3b4b7502.json"))
```

Try to use instead

```
OAuth.class.getResourceAsStream("/keys/app-name-c0cc3b4b7502.json"))
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but now it cannot find the class itself in question. Can you please check the new error log. Thanks.

Comment: Check whether correct version of the library is included.

Comment: I solved that one, can you please check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141703/spring-mvc-google-calendar-no-such-method-com-google-api-client-json-jsonfacto